# How can i use complex analysis for this integral (?)

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to evaluate this integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100616/how-to-evaluate-this-integral)

Let $b>0$. Evaluate the next value of integral:

$$\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos x}{x^2 + b^2} \ dx
\end{equation}$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#Example

Comment: Replace $\cos x$ by $\operatorname{Re} e^{ix}$.

Comment: yes, this integral is with the Cauchy's method of residues. I don't remenber. Long time, i did not see this.

Comment: I remembering doing this same exact integral in class. Wierd. The answer comes out as $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{be^{b}}$ after you evaluate the residue at $x = ib$

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with the residue theorem, you know
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty R(x)e^{ix}dx=2\pi i\sum_{y>0}\mathrm{Res}R(z)e^{iz}
$$
where $R(x)$ is some rational function. However, the real part of this integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty R(x)\cos(x)dx,
$$
so the integral you want is just the real part of 
$$
2\pi i\sum_{y>0}\mathrm{Res}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+b^2}.
$$
Note that the sum is over residues in the upper half plane. Note that the poles occur at $\pm bi$, and since $b>0$, the only residue you need to worry about is at $bi$. Can you proceed?

Comment: thanks for reminding me, I'll finish the details, I need to see the way

Comment: Sure, if you need any more help, don't hesitate to ask.