# solve integral with residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I want to show that for positive $a$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+a^2}} dx = \frac{\pi e^{-a}}{a}$$

I'm not even sure how to define a smart contour… I guess it can't be a half circle, since $\cos(z)$ is unbounded for big imaginary parts. If I take a rectangle, then the vertical lines will have no impact in the limit since $\cos(z)$ is bounded there and $\frac{1}{z^2}$ decreases rapidly, but for the "way back" i can't find a good choice since the nominator isn't periodic… :(

Comment: As a function on the whole complex plane I choose $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}$, so I just have to take the real part of the solution in the end

Comment: oh there will be problems for the way back with this choice-.-

Comment: A closed semi-circular contour works. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100616/how-to-evaluate-this-integral)

Comment: Integrating $e^{iz}/(z^2+a^2)$ over the upper semicircle, we have just one pole.

Comment: thanks…omg i failed calculating the residue correctly and so i tried to find my mistake^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is rather simple, first we evaluate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i  x}}{x^2+a^2}dx$$ 
using half a circle as you suggested, this function has no problem since the $e^{i  z}$ is bounded in upper half plane. The residue theorem yields
  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i  x}}{x^2+a^2}dx=2\pi i\frac{e^{-a}}{2ia}=\frac{\pi}{a} e^{-a}$$ 
Taking real parts of both side give you rhe answer.